# Python Dictionary seems correct, but isn't working

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently trying to work on a basic Python dictionary where you input an RNA code, and it gives you the corresponding amino acids. Everything seems to work fine, until I type either "UCU", "UCC", "UCA", "UCG". Why will it not work? Can anyone identify the problem?

Here's the actual code:

```
while True:
  n = 3
  xdict = {
      "Phenylalanine": ["UUU", "UUC"],
      "Leucine": ["UUA", "CUU", "CUC", "CUA", "CUG", "UUG"],
      "Isoleucine": ["AUU", "AUC", "AUA"],
      "Methionine": ["AUG"],
      "Valine": ["GUU", "GUC", "GUA", "GUG"],
      "Serine": ["UCU", "UCC", "UCA", "UCG"],
      "Proline": ["CCU", "CCC", "CCA", "CCG"],
      "Threonine": ["ACU", "ACC", "ACA", "ACG"],
      "Alanine": ["GCU", "GCC", "GCA", "GCG"],
      "Tyrosine": ["UAU", "UAC"],
      "Histidine": ["CAU", "CAC"],
      "Glutamine": ["CAA", "CAG"],
      "Asparagine": ["AAU", "AAC"],
      "Lysine": ["AAA", "AAG"],
      "Asparatic Acid": ["GAU", "GAC"],
      "Glutamic Acid": ["GAA", "GAG"],
      "Cysteine": ["UGU", "UGC"],
      "Trytophan": ["UGG"],
      "Arginine": ["CGU", "CGC", "CGA", "CGG", "AGG", "AGA"],
      "Serine": ["AGU", "AGC"],
      "Glycine": ["GGU", "GGC", "GGA", "GGG"]}
  lookup_dict = {k: key for key, values in xdict.items() for k in values}
  a = input("Please enter your RNA sequence: ")
  a = a.upper()
  print("The messenger RNA strand is:", a)
  b = len(a)
  val = ''
  if b % 3 == 0:
    for k in (a[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(a), n)):
      val += lookup_dict[k] + ' '
    val += " "
  elif b % 3 != 0:
    print("Try again.", end = "")
  val = val.replace("  ", "")
  print("Your amino acids chain is:", val)
```

Here's what the output was after I input of cccccgggguca

```
Please enter your RNA sequence: cccccgggguca
The messenger RNA strand is: CCCCCGGGGUCA
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 33, in <module>
    val += lookup_dict[k] + ' '
KeyError: 'UCA'
```

Thank you kindly to everyone out there, and I hope that others might learn from my errors too.

Comment: "Everything seems to work fine, until I type either "UCU", "UCC", "UCA", "UCG"." What should the result be when you type one of those? How is the program supposed to calculate that result - where does the data come from? In particular: look at your initial `xdict`. Do you see any of those strings anywhere?

Comment: You have duplicate `"Serine"` keys in the initial dictionary.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Cheers mate - this solved my problem

Comment: @CodeAJ Just a note, a good IDE would have pointed that out for you. You may benefit from upgrading to a better environment.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Any suggestions?

Comment: I use Pycharm, but it's quite a large program. I imagine any decent static analysis plugin for any editor would catch mistakes like this as well.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thank you for all of this extra recommendations. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simplify your code to the following

```
def get_amino_acid(rna):
    xdict = {
      "Phenylalanine": ["UUU", "UUC"],
      "Leucine": ["UUA", "CUU", "CUC", "CUA", "CUG", "UUG"],
      "Isoleucine": ["AUU", "AUC", "AUA"],
      "Methionine": ["AUG"],
      "Valine": ["GUU", "GUC", "GUA", "GUG"],
      "Serine": ["UCU", "UCC", "UCA", "UCG"],
      "Proline": ["CCU", "CCC", "CCA", "CCG"],
      "Threonine": ["ACU", "ACC", "ACA", "ACG"],
      "Alanine": ["GCU", "GCC", "GCA", "GCG"],
      "Tyrosine": ["UAU", "UAC"],
      "Histidine": ["CAU", "CAC"],
      "Glutamine": ["CAA", "CAG"],
      "Asparagine": ["AAU", "AAC"],
      "Lysine": ["AAA", "AAG"],
      "Asparatic Acid": ["GAU", "GAC"],
      "Glutamic Acid": ["GAA", "GAG"],
      "Cysteine": ["UGU", "UGC"],
      "Trytophan": ["UGG"],
      "Arginine": ["CGU", "CGC", "CGA", "CGG", "AGG", "AGA"],
      "Glycine": ["GGU", "GGC", "GGA", "GGG"]
    }

    return [key for key, value in xdict.items() if rna in value]
```

Then it will handle cases where no amino acid contains that rna

```
>>> get_amino_acid('UCU')
[]
>>> get_amino_acid('AGU')
['Serine']
>>> get_amino_acid('CAC')
['Histidine']
```

Also as noted by @Carcigenicate you have an additional `"Serine"` key that can be removed.